# AudioKit microphone input + MIDI output

Tags: ios, objective-c, audiokit, mikmidi

**Is it possible to use [AudioKit](https://github.com/audiokit/AudioKit) to gather microphone input and simultaneously use [MIKMIDI](https://github.com/mixedinkey-opensource/MIKMIDI) for playing notes from a MIDI file through the stereo speakers?**

I have found that I can successfully do each on their own; I can gather microphone frequencies from AudioKit and play notes from a MIDI file with MIKMIDI, but if I use them together, then the MIDI notes are played on an 'internal hardware speaker' (not quite sure of the actual name? kind of like a DOS game), not the stereo speaker, and the notes are extremely low in amplitude.

### AudioKit Usage

This is literally the only piece of code I use to obtain the microphone frequencies. *There is other code that I use that frequency data for, but it is irrelevant.* Point being, if I comment out this piece of code, the MIKMIDI portion works as expected and plays through the stereo speakers.

```
- (void)setupAudio
{
    AKSettings.audioInputEnabled = true;

    self.microphone = [[AKMicrophone alloc] init];
    self.tracker = [[AKFrequencyTracker alloc] init:self.microphone hopSize:0 peakCount:0];
    self.silence = [[AKBooster alloc] init:self.tracker gain:0];

    [AudioKit setOutput:self.silence];
    [AudioKit start];
}
```

### MIKMIDI Usage

```
- (void)playMidi:(NSUInteger)note withDuration:(float)duration
{
    if ( [DEFAULTS boolForKey:kPreferenceMIDIPlaybackEnabled] )
    {
        NSDate * startDate = [NSDate date];
        NSDate * endDate = [startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:duration];

        MIKMIDINoteOnCommand * noteOn = [MIKMIDINoteOnCommand noteOnCommandWithNote:note velocity:127 channel:0 timestamp:startDate];
        MIKMIDINoteOffCommand * noteOff = [MIKMIDINoteOffCommand noteOffCommandWithNote:note velocity:0 channel:0 timestamp:endDate];

        [self.synthesizer handleMIDIMessages:@[noteOn, noteOff]];
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with your implementation but MIKMIDI and AudioKit might be fighting over some audio configuration settings.